# SMTP + Gmail error : mail not send

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to send email. This is the code that I have written.

```
config['protocol']      = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'mymail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = '123';
$config['mailtype']     = 'html';
$config['charset']      = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;    
$config['newline']      = "\r\n";
```

Here's the error i'm getting:

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed outUnable to send email using PHP  SMTP. Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.
>
> ```
> User-Agent:
> CodeIgniter
> ```
>
> `Date: Wed, 24 May 2017 14:39:24 +0530
>  From: &quot;SMEC&quot; &lt;contact@labs.info&gt;
>  Return-Path: &lt;contact@labs.info&gt;
>  Reply-To: &lt;training@labs.org&gt;
>  To: test00@gmail.com
>  Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=53=4D=45=43=4C=61=62=73=20=2D=20=43=41=52=45=45=52=20=49?= =?ISO-8859-1?Q?=4E=20=43=4F=52=45=20=49=4E=44=55=53=54=52=49=45=53=21=21?=    
>  X-Sender: contact@labs.info
>  X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
>  X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>  Message-ID: &ltgt;
>  Mime-Version: 1.0
>  Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=&quot;B_ALT_59254dc4bc79e&quot;
>
>  This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>  Your email application may not support this format.`

Comment: try gmail instead of googlemail

Comment: You have to set access for less trusted apps in your Gmail account also.. is it so??

Answer (score 0):

The below configuration works perfectly for me even with Gmail.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'example@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] ='yourmailpassword';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

$this->email->from('from@gmail.com', 'TEST MAIL');
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($subject);
$this->email->message($message);

$this->email->send();
```

Don't forget to enable less trusted app access in your Gmail account. I was able to send both simple text emails and emails with HTML templates and images with above configuration without any problem.

Comment: In addition to this answer, try going to:
https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and unlock the account - it deactivates any captcha that may be asked for.
To assure there is no network problem, try connecting to gmail using simple telnet.